# Tibia Error on Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, games

I have a bit of a problem, I'm trying to play [Tibia](http://www.tibia.com/news/?subtopic=latestnews) on my 11.10 installation and I get the following error:

> ./Tibia: error while loading shared libraries: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

All I used to do to play was download, extract and run the game. I'm running a 64bit installation of 11.10.

Any ideas?

Here's the output to ldd on the file:

```
amatteo@adrian-Ubuntu:~/Tibia$ ldd ./Tibia
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf76e1000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1 (0xf75f8000)
libGLU.so.1 => not found
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf74c1000)
librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf74b8000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf73cd000)
libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf73a3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7385000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf720a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf71ef000)
libnvidia-tls.so.280.13 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.280.13 (0xf71ec000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.280.13 => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libnvidia-glcore.so.280.13 (0xf58db000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf58c8000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf58c2000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf58a3000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76e2000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf589f000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf5898000)
```

I made a search for `libGLU.so.1` and it was found in */usr/lib* and in */usr/lib32*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `dpkg -S libGLU.so.1`, you need to install either `ia32-libs` or `libglu1-mesa` package:

```
$ dpkg -S libGLU.so.1
ia32-libs: /usr/lib32/libGLU.so.1
ia32-libs: /usr/lib32/libGLU.so.1.3.070701
libglu1-mesa: /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1.3.070701
libglu1-mesa: /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1
```

I'd recommend you to go with `libglu1-mesa`, because `ia32-libs` is combined library package, and it's quite a big.

In other words:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa
```

Comment: Please note, `dpkg` output is from 10.04, but the same should be applicable for 11.10 as well.

Comment: If you don't know what to do with the commands in the answer, you may press CTRL+ALT+T and then ***type*** the command(Or paste with right-click>PASTE as Terminal uses Ctrl_V for something else.) In this case, it's the last but of text in the gray box.

Comment: I made a search for libGLU.so.1 in /usr/lib and it's there, it's also in /usr/lib32 so i don't know what's wrong!

Comment: The solution was close, but libglu1-mesa was already installed so I installed ia32-libs and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of Ubuntu you can get away with just:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386
```

Comment: Can you advise of why or what difference this might make?